# Error in android - SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am trying to query my database to return the name entered into a text box. I have been able to view all the items in the database but i want to search for a name using a text box. When I enter the name and hit the search button, the log cat displays an error that "no such column: john: while compiling: SELECT name, gender, height, age, hair FROM details WHERE name= john ORDER by name.

```
 private void findRecords(){
    EditText find = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameSearch);
    EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameFound);
    EditText gender = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.genderFound);
    String s = find.getText().toString();
    //Long l = Long.parseLong(s);
    DatabaseClass hon = new DatabaseClass(this);

    String returnedName = hon.getName(s);
    String returnedGender = hon.getGender(s);

    name.setText(returnedName);
    gender.setText(returnedGender);

}


    public String getName(String s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] {NAME_COLUMN, GENDER_COLUMN, HEIGHT_COLUMN, AGE_COLUMN, HAIR_COLUMN};
    Cursor c = sherlockdb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, NAME_COLUMN +"="+ s, null, null, null, NAME_COLUMN);
    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String name = c.getString(1);
        return name;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Please kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cursor c = sherlockdb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, NAME_COLUMN +"='"+ s+"'", null, null, null, NAME_COLUMN);
```

Because you need String in 'john' format.

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
Cursor c = sherlockdb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, NAME_COLUMN +"="+ s, null, null, null, NAME_COLUMN);
```

with:

```
String[] args={s};
Cursor c = sherlockdb.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, NAME_COLUMN +"=?", args, null, null, NAME_COLUMN);
```

Comment: If i replace it with String[] args={s}, i can't use the "columns" and i need that to read the data

Comment: @user1642943 You don't replace `columns`, they stay the way they were: http://pastebin.com/PFWS7Lnn

Comment: @user1642943: Your problem is that the value of `s` (apparently `john`) is not the name of a column. If you want that to be treated as a string, you need to quote it. The best way to quote it is to let SQLite do it, via query parameters (the `?` in the revised `query()` call). That way, it will also handling escaping any embedded quotation marks within the value.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of data is your column? I think that you forgot to put the literal jonh between ''.

You can try this:

```
SELECT name, gender, height, age, hair FROM details WHERE name='john' ORDER by name;
```